# HTML Formatted Emails With Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, format, html-email

Disclaimer: beginner

Hi, I am trying to build a formatted email sender. I want it to be able to send emails to a user entered list of emails and have it format to a list of names so that it sends each email formatted. Does anyone know a way to do this?

I'd also like it to not have the formatting where there is no name present in the list. So when there is no name present in the list, the email will just appear as "Hi!, blah etc."

Currently, it will format the first name but will only send one email and will format any additional names from the list to the one email(comes out like "Hi ben, dave").

I have another model which I'm working on that uses .csv files, before anyone suggests that approach, but I'd like to have a model using input lists, if for nothing else but to see how and if it would work.

Also credit to python codex, credit where credit is due.

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage


host = "smtp.gmail.com"
port = 587
username = "xxx@gmail.com"
password = "xxx"
from_email = username
to_list = input('Please enter emails seperated by a comma: ')
Name_list = input('Please enter names seperated by a comma: ')
email_conn = smtplib.SMTP(host, port)
email_conn.ehlo()
email_conn.starttls()
email_conn.login(username, password)


the_msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
the_msg['Subject'] = "Link"
the_msg["From"] = "xxx@gmail.com"
the_msg["To"] = to_list

plain_txt = "Hi!\nHow are you?\nHere is the link you wanted:\nhttp://www.python.org"
html_txt = """\
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <p>Hi {name}!<br>
       How are you?<br>
       Here is the <a href="http://www.python.org">link</a> you wanted.<br>
       <img src="cid:image1">
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
""".format(name=Name_list)


fp = open('/Users/xxx/xxx.png', 'rb')
msgImage = MIMEImage(fp.read())
fp.close()


msgImage.add_header('Content-ID', '<image1>')
the_msg.attach(msgImage)


part_1 = MIMEText(plain_txt, 'plain')
part_2 = MIMEText(html_txt, "html")
the_msg.attach(part_1)
the_msg.attach(part_2)


print(the_msg.as_string())


from smtplib import SMTP, SMTPAuthenticationError, SMTPException

pass_wrong = SMTP(host, port)
pass_wrong.ehlo()
pass_wrong.starttls()
try:
    pass_wrong.login(username, "wrong_password")
    pass_wrong.sendmail(from_email, to_list, "")
except SMTPAuthenticationError:
    print("Message sent")
except:
    print("an error occured")

pass_wrong.quit()

email_conn.sendmail(from_email, to_list, the_msg.as_string())
email_conn.quit()
```

Comment: you can easily get the list as a csv file. load the csv into python and loop through the list while calling an email method, and you can add various checks.

Comment: Don't send email with everyone in "to" would/could make lots of people angry. Go with the CSV file, loop over email-name pairs and send 1 email at a time.